# How to place labels and buttons in frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame, python-3.5

How do I place the username and password label along with the login button inside the f2 box. Because, at the moment the f1 and f2 is covering the labels and button.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def adminLogin():
    global AnameEL
    global ApwordEL # More globals :D
    global ArootA

    ArootA = Tk() # This now makes a new window.
    ArootA.geometry('1280x720')
    ArootA.title('Admin login') # This makes the window title 'login'

    f1 = Frame(width=200, height=200, background="#D3D3D3")
    f2 = Frame(width=400, height=200, background="#b4b4b4")

    f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
    f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

    AnameL = Label(ArootA, text='Username: ') # More labels
    ApwordL = Label(ArootA, text='Password: ') # ^
    AnameL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    ApwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    AnameEL = Entry(ArootA) # The entry input
    ApwordEL = Entry(ArootA, show='*')
    AnameEL.grid(row=1, column=1)
    ApwordEL.grid(row=2, column=1)

    AloginB = Button(ArootA, text='Login')
    AloginB.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

adminLogin()
```

I would like this:
[image]

to be placed in this dark grey smaller box in the middle:

[image]

Comment: Note that `Tk()` doesn't just create a window exactly. It creates _the_ root window that is the parent to the widgets that are created w/o passing a parent such as `f1` and `f2` _unless_ there is already an instance of `Tk`. If you've created other widgets before this function, then there definitely is. Essentally making your `f1` and `f2` instead the children of that very first instance of `Tk` thus the answers provided here may not be easily integrated to your entire script.

Comment: Note that running this code generates an error because you're trying to use all three geometry managers inside the very same parent, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create widgets, like Frames and Labels and Entry's and Buttons, the first arg you pass is the "parent" or "master" arg. That arg determines where Tkinter puts the widget. So, if you want your widgets to show up in a certain frame, then pass that frame rather than ArootA when you create the widgets.

In particular, since you want the widgets inside f2, pass f2 instead of ArootA as the first arg when creating those widgets.

When you create the Frames, you **should** pass in the root widget, ArootA. So:

```
f2 = Frame(width=400, ...
```

should really be:

```
f2 = Frame(ArootA, width=400, ...
```

And since you want the widgets to be in f2, change:

```
AnameL = Label(ArootA, ...
```

to

```
AnameL = Label(f2, ...
```

etc, and that should give you the result that you want.